# Joomla SP Smart Slider - JQuery pause animation on mouseover / hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, joomla, slider

I'm using an jQuery Slider on a webpage and would like to pause the animation if the user hovers the slide.

Unfortunatley I'm a complete jQuery looser :( and I hope there is someone who can solve this easily...

Slider can be found here:
http://demo.joomshaper.com/joomla25/minima/

Comment: According to one of the Support member on the forum, this feature doesn't exist.

Comment: Yes I know - thats why I'm hoping to find a solution here... ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this [CK slide show](http://www.joomlack.fr/en/joomla-extensions/slideshow-ck). . . .

EDIT:
Thats what CK slide show says

> Slideshow CK can display your images or videos with nice effects. It
>   is compatible with mobiles, resonsive design (adaptive width) and you
>   can slide with your fingers on your mobile. You can easily manage the
>   slide in the module options with a Drag & Drop interface.

I used it in my websites. It is robust, easy to use, customisable and a most important is that its free. [DOWNLOAD](http://www.joomlack.fr/en/component/dms/view_document/59-slideshow-ck)

And slider also stops when mouse hover over it.